# How to swap two views frame and also swap them in their view hierarchy in swift?

Tags: swift, animation

I have two views, say view1 and view2 added to a superview. View1 is in front and has a bigger frame than view2 which is behind, the top of the view2 is visible above view1 to make it look like a deck of cards. When user swipes view1 horizontally, it should go behind view2 and view2 should come in front. I am not sure how to achieve this, i need to exchange two views position and exchange them in view hierarchy in one animation. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if
    let firstIndex = view.subviews.firstIndex(of: firstView),
    let secondIndex = view.subviews.firstIndex(of: secondView)
{
    let firstViewFrame = firstView.frame
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        self.firstView.frame = self.secondView.frame
        self.secondView.frame = firstViewFrame
        self.view.exchangeSubview(at: firstIndex, withSubviewAt: secondIndex)
    })
}
```

Example: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jAUokRRuUNtFmmtI1sBVh_eMpf3gUylV

Comment: Hey @hell0friend , I've tried this but this doesn't change the views frame, it just makes the firstview  go behind the secondView with a weird animation, maybe I setup the view using constraints is the reason this is not working.

Comment: I've found a solution though, I remove both view from superview and add them with the according to the desired hierarchy and constraints, that works like a charm but it is a loot of code.

Comment: There is no other way if you use constraints, but instead of removing both views you can use exchangeSubview function